# Error in oneHot: depth must be >=2, but it is 1

Tags: javascript, p5.js, ml5.js

So I was working with ml5 in js on a simple NeuralNetwork that was going to be trained by images using the p5 js lib to get the images into a array and then train them through ml5, But I ran into a major issue that I have been spending hours looking for the answer of this error but cant find it anywhere.
Using Libraries p5,p5.sound,sketch,ml5

**Js File**

```
let RustImage = [];

function preload() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        RustImage[i] = loadImage(`RustPhotos/2020-12-08 (${i+7}).png`);

    }
}
let NodeClassifier;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(440, 440);
    // background(0);
    // image(RustImage[0], 0, 0, width, height);

    let options = {
        inputs: [128, 128, 4],
        task: "imageClassification",
        debug: true,
    };

    NodeClassifier = ml5.neuralNetwork(options);

    for (let i = 0; i < RustImage.length; i++) {
        NodeClassifier.addData({ image: RustImage[i] }, { label: "SulfurNode" });
    }
    NodeClassifier.normalizeData();
    NodeClassifier.train({ epochs: 5 }, finishedTraining);

}

function finishedTraining() {
    console.log("Finished Training!");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Getting Started with ml5.js</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.sound.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="improring.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If anybody can help and they know the answer to this error or a simple fix, Please comment.

**FULL ERROR**

```
Uncaught Error: Error in oneHot: depth must be >=2, but it is 1
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.esm.js:17
oneHot_ @ c:\Users\mattd\Desktop\Xamp\htdocs\Js Importing Lib\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.esm.js:17:357944
oneHot @ c:\Users\mattd\Desktop\Xamp\htdocs\Js Importing Lib\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.esm.js:17:71801
◀ load ▶
<anonymous> @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:65707:28
◀ Promise.then ▶
_main.default.loadImage @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:65671:30
<anonymous> @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:48748:67
preload @ C:\Users\mattd\Desktop\Xamp\htdocs\Js Importing Lib\improring.js:5:24
_start @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:48706:19
p5 @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:49057:22
_globalInit @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:48197:17
◀ Promise.then ▶
51.../core/main @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:48222:71
o @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:34:19
<anonymous> @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:38:22
38../color/color_conversion @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:41211:11
o @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:34:19
r @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:51:9
<anonymous> @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:55:7
<anonymous> @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:18:12
<anonymous> @ cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js:20:3
```

Comment: It would be worth adding the complete stack trace of the error you get so that we can have an idea of which line is causing the issue otherwise not a lot of people might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is the same, but in my case some of the training datasets had only 1 single outcome of the output label, thus model would not train.

It seems to somehow match with the "depth must be >=2, but it is 1" message.

To be sure I just add another outcome manually in the dataset and relaunch